# How to delete columns with repetitive column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, del

I have merge 26 csv files (each containing 3 columns) into 1 dataframe. So, in total I have 78 columns. Now, column 1 is similar to columns 4, 7, 10 and so on. Similarly, column 2 is similar to columns 5, 8, 11, etc. The column names are also similar and I need to delete them all except for column 2 because 1 need 1 occurrence of it. Below is my coding. I have tried renaming column 2 and then deleting the rest but I have the following error:

Error: Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:

- "PI" at locations 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc.
- "POS" at locations 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, etc.

coding:

```
colname <- names(df.combined)
colname[2] <- paste(colname[2], "_chrom")
colnames(df.combined) <- colname

library(dplyr) 
df.combined <- select(df.combined, -CHROM).
```

Besides, may be there is a better way to rename column 2 because I could only change it from POS to POS_chrom. Actually I wanted to give it a new name rather than adding _chrom to it.
The column names are as follows (simplified example) after renaming the second column. It goes on like this until column 78.
CHROM  POS_chrom  PI  CHROM  POS  PI  CHROM POS  PI

This is my coding that I wrote to merge the files into 1 dataframe:

```
library(data.table)

file_list <- list.files('/home/aahm/SoftMaker/Documents/Aaisha/MPhil_PhD/2021/1.January/Results/csv_files/sitepi/ACKR2', pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

ldf <- lapply(file_list , read.csv)
df.combined <- do.call(cbind, ldf)
View (df.combined)
```

This is part of my dataframe containing 6 columns and 8 rows, but the actual dataset is much larger than this and I have to repeat the same process several times.

CHROM   POS PI  CHROM   POS PI
3   42809473    0   3   42809473    0
3   42809498    0.01042 3   42809498    0
3   42809524    0   3   42809524    0
3   42809625    0   3   42809625    0
3   42809638    0   3   42809638    0
3   42809715    0.30628 3   42809715    0.20485
3   42809846    0   3   42809846    0

Actually I need columns 2,3,6,9,12,x,y,z,78 in the final dataframe where x, y and z are multiples of 3.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of `df.combined`? Use at least `dput(df.combined[1:5,])` to provide the first rows.

Comment: How did you combine them into one dataframe? Can you show the columns that you have in `df.combined` and what you want to change them to?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `merge`.

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. I have added the requested additional information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following code:

```
library(data.table)

file_list <- list.files('/home/ahus/Softmaker/ACKR2', pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

ldf <- lapply(file_list , read.csv)
df.combined <- do.call(cbind, ldf)
x <- seq(0,78,by=3)
df.restructured <- df.combined[c(2,x)]
```